# Testing ARKit without iPhone6s or newer

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9, arkit

I am before decision to download Xcode9. I want to play with new framework - ARKit. I know that to run app with ARKit I need a device with A9 chip or newer. Unfortunately I have an older one. My question is to people who already downloaded the new Xcode. There is a possibility to run ARKit app in my case? Any simulator for that or something else? Any ideas or will I have to buy new device?

Comment: For AR you need Camera ... So Simulator is not possible

Comment: Did you have iPAD pro?

Comment: I know that iPadPro has good chip but I don't have proper iPad too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ARKit is available on any iOS 11 device, but the world tracking features that enable high-quality AR experiences require a device with the A9 or later processor.It is Necessary to update your device with iOS 11 beta.

Comment: so I have chance to build and run ARKit app on my device if I will update iOS?

Comment: Yes Sure, Update your iPhone with iOS 11 beta using developer account. ARSample [link](https://developer.apple.com/sample-code/wwdc/2017/PlacingObjects.zip) will work awesome.

Comment: it does not work you can try the ARsample, it is not working. you need iphone 6s or newer.

Answer (score 5):

There is another problem due to iOS11 beta1 bug, [iOS 11 Beta 1 Release Notes And Known Issues According To Apple](http://www.redmondpie.com/ios-11-beta-1-release-notes-changes-and-known-issues-according-to-apple/)

[image: snapsoht image]

This means you need an iPhone 6S or better to use ARKit(ARSessionConfiguration) at the current time. Until the iOS11 beta2 release...

> 2017.07.13 update

My iphone6 had update to iOS11 beta3, and it can run ARWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration, amazing!

> 2017.09.07 update

iphone6 can not run ARWorldTrackingConfiguration in recently iOS11 beta...... :(