# How to use ARKit on older iOS devices?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios11, arkit

With beta version of iOS 11, ARKit apps crash even when using 3DOF which should be compatible with older devices?

And how can I prevent app crash, if ARKit is not supported?

Comment: Which device are you using? It's going tombe hard to help you without some code sample and crash logs

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44567920/testing-arkit-without-iphone6s-or-newer and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44590817/arkit-demo-crashing-on-iphone-6-iphone-6-plus?rq=1

Answer (score 10):

## Supported Devices

As of iOS 11, you [can't](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit) use ARKit on old devices:

> **Important**
>
> ARKit requires an iOS device with an A9 or later processor.
>
> To make your app available only on devices supporting ARKit, use the
> arkit key in the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities section of your app's
> Info.plist. If augmented reality is a secondary feature of your app,
> use the  isSupported  property to determine whether the current device
> supports the session configuration you want to use.

Device should have A9 or later processor. You can use only:

- iPhone SE,
- iPhone 6S and newer (7, 8, X),
- iPad (2017) or newer,
- iPad Pro (any).

## Preventing Crashes

To prevent app crash, you can use [isSupported](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arconfiguration/2923553-issupported) property of `ARConfiguration`. And don't forget to check current iOS version.

```
import ARKit

func isARSupported() -> Bool {
    guard #available(iOS 11.0, *) else {
        return false
    }
    return ARConfiguration.isSupported
}

if isARSupported() {
    // ARKit is supported. Do what you need.
} else {
    // ARKit is not supported.
}
```

> Before attempting to create an AR configuration, verify that the
> user’s device supports the configuration you plan to use by checking
> the isSupported property of the corresponding configuration class. If
> this property’s value is false, the current device does not support
> the requested configuration.

Comment: A good answer would at least say which iPhone has an A9 processor.

Comment: It's not true. 3DOF is supported on all apple devices, its what were said on WWDC I believe. 6DOF is A9 and later

Comment: @SomeUser this is what apple said in their documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit

Comment: A9 devices include iPhone 6s or later, iPhone SE, every iPad Pro, and the 2017 iPad (just "iPad", aka iPad 5th gen).

Comment: Also this is `beta` and a lot could be changed in final version.

Comment: Note that Apple's AR Kit is the result of [purchasing Metaio](https://www.recode.net/2015/5/29/11563122/apple-buys-german-augmented-reality-software-maker-metaio), whose SDK *does* [run fine](https://www.theverge.com/2015/5/28/8682505/apple-acquires-metaio-augmented-reality-startup) on older devices, if you can get ahold of it anymore. In fact, I worked on a team which used Metaio to make [this](https://vimeo.com/194551673), which, as you can see, works fine on older hardware.